# Computed Field in Sitecore using Solr and Analyzers

Tags: solr, content-search, computed-field

I'm trying to use an analyzer on my computed field to allow searching with spaces.  Nothing I've tried works yet.  Any ideas?

```
<contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
          <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
              <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                  <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
                      <field fieldName="firstlastname" storageType="yes" indexType="tokenized" type="string">
                        <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                      </field>
                  </fieldNames>
              </fieldMap>
              <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                  <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
                      <field fieldName="firstlastname" storageType="yes" indexType="tokenized"> Sitecore.Fields.FirstLastNameComputedField, Circle.Fields</field>
                  </fields>
              </documentOptions>
          </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
  </contentSearch>
```

Answer (score 1):

To have included spaces into your index at population you need to specify `indexType="UNTOKENIZED"`, and then at the indexing the spaces are not removed.

If you want to use analyser, your current analyser removes spaces and converts them into lowercase.
Example:
Input: "I just *LOVE* my Phone!"
Output: "i", "just", "love", "my", "phone"

Check other analyzer if you want spaces and use untokenized for computed index field:

```
<field fieldName="firstlastname" storageType="yes" indexType="UNTOKENIZED"> Sitecore.Fields.FirstLastNameComputedField, Circle.Fields</field>
                  </fields>
```

More details about tokenizers: https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_4/tokenizers.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when it changed but in Sitecore 10.x you now need to change the `returnType` parameter which is used for whether the field gets tokenized or not. For example `string` does not get tokenized but `text` does.

```
<field fieldName="firstlastname" returnType="string"> Sitecore.Fields.FirstLastNameComputedField, Circle.Fields</field>
                  </fields>
```